# Is it true for every sequence $a_n$ that if $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent, then $\sum (-1)^n a_n$ is convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

The problem is in the title.

I must answer the question whether it's true for every sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is absolutely convergent then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n a_n$ is convergent. Here is what I came up with:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |(-1)^n a_n|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|$ which is convergent by assumption.

So  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n a_n$ is absolutely convergent which implies that it is convergent as well.

Is it correct?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$